# Accessing Web-Services from Android which are accessible through VPN on Web

Tags: android, vpn, android-vpn-service

I have a application i know how to consume web services i am up with a challenge and lack of knowledge on network side,
The Web Services are accessible through VPN on Web which is protected with
Credentials.

I am looking around connecting VPN Service [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService) and tried the sample look , poked around OPENVPN and ToyVPN,

My Question is do i need a VPN service to consume the web services or is their something which i am missing because i do not have much of knowledge regarding this.

Below is the code i am using as i mentioned earlier VPN server has Creds but the method below i am using returns me isConnected true even though i haven't provided the Creds.

```
 builder.addAddress(ServerAddress, 24)
                        .addDnsServer("8.8.8.8")
                        .addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0).establish();

                InetSocketAddress server = new InetSocketAddress(
                        ServerAddress, portNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to add VPN implementation in your app. You will need to find out from Web service author, which VPN app (available on Play store) you should use to setup VPN beforehand. Once your VPN is connected, your app should be able to access the web service.